# Twitter Bootstrap: make contents of a row or row-fluid not wrap and overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap has a 12 column grid and when you exceed the columns with your content, the content wraps (example below).

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <p>foo</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <p>bar</p>
    </div>
    <div class="span6"> <!-- the extra content which will wrap -->
        <p>baz</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the content to stay on the same line and overflow (essentially i am designing a matrix and wrapping does not work well with matrices). I have looked at floating the child elements (`span6`s) and setting the `overflow` to `auto` on `row-fluid`, but that does not work.

Are there any possible solutions to this?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to make sure your "span-count" does not exceed 12. In your case when you have 3 columns you should use "span4" instead of "span6".

See http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem for details. The Grid is designed around 12 columns and while you can have less it will misbehave if you have more. If you like to have more you would have to override the CSS classes for spanX to make sure the total width does not exceed 100%.

Comment: if i have more than 12 columns, how do i get the extra to overflow and not wrap? Is there any easy way to do this?

Comment: While I would not recommend doing the CSS overrides, if you absolutely have to you I am guessing it's because you're not happy with the total width? In that case you should probably use row-fluid and figure out the new percentage widths for the spans (span4 currently has default width: 31.623931623931625%). Again, I would strongly recommend not doing it and rather adapt to a 12 col layout or find another grid that has 16.

Comment: The problem is the column count can be arbitrarily large, so adjusting the percentages won't do the trick. Overflow: auto and float: left does not get them to overflow either.

Comment: In that case I would probably not use the grid system at all (it's optional). It doesn't sound like it's very well suited for your needs.